# Bullseye xml output evenent parameter in probe lines

Tags: tools, regression-testing, xml-file

I just started working with Bullseye and i export the results to xml, most part of the results are easy to understand. But there is an parameter called event, which i don't really understand what it is used for.
What kind of metric is it? And what is it used for?
Example output below:

```
<probe line="xxx" kind="decision" event="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of anyone else needing this information, i got in touch with the provider and got this response:

The event can be one of none, false, true, full. None means no coverage.
True and false mean the probe is for a condition or decision. Full means all
coverage occurred. If the probe is a condition or decision, that means both
true and false happened. If any other kind of probe, such as function entry,
full means it happened.